# Getting data from a plist file iOS sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, plist

I am creating a sprite kit game where i want to use plist files for storing variables. (I am new to this and there are not enough tutorials on creating levels using plists.)

My question is that, i have  about 60 to 70 variables that i want to load in the game. There must be about 50 variables that need to be loaded once only in the entire game and then about 20 that are level specific and change with level change.

What is the way to load so many variables? Will reading from plist not make my game slow at loading time? Also if i want to write the results of each level in the plist file, will i need to use the same plist file or i can create multiple of different levels. Can anyone clear this confusion and suggest some good tutorial which throughly explains plist creation for games.

Comment: Asking for tutorial is off-topic. Speculating about performance is moot if you don't have any code yet. Most ObjC collections can save to and read from plist format, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: and https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303

Answer (score 0):

Plist loading is pretty fast. If XML plists are not fast enough or are too big, switch to binary plists.

The Property List Serialization guide from Apple should get you started.

NSDictionary and NSArray have plist convenience methods also.

If you have a set of data that is static that's one plist. If you have a set that is per level that is either another plist or a plist per level.

Per level makes sense for scalability.